# Post a photo on Facebook wall

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, photo

Please recommend an image sharing service that can be called programmatically to upload a photo.  I want to use the returned response and post a link to that photo or album in a Facebook message on wall.

The problem is that Facebook doesn't allow to use an uploaded photo within Facebook to be used in the wall message whereas external domains are allowed.

Can flickr be used? I don't want the users to login to flickr though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Imgur? http://api.imgur.com/

Comment: RajenK, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I believe this will work.